# SQL query to select e.g. buyer which made 3 specific buys

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this:

**ToyStore**

```
+----+------------+-------------------+ 
| ID | NAME       | PURCHASE          | 
+----+------------+-------------------+
| 1  | Ramesh     | Teddy bear        |
| 2  | Khilan     | Drum              | 
| 3  | Chaitali   | Chess             | 
| 4  | Hardik     | Wooden sword      | 
|... | ...        | ...               |
+----+------------+-------------------+
```

I need to select all the buyers which have made all 3 purchases - Teddy bear, Chess and Wooden sword and their purchases

As a result there should be something like this:

```
+--------+-------------------+ 
| NAME   | PURCHASE          | 
+--------+-------------------+
| Ramesh | Teddy bear        |
| Ramesh | Chess             | 
| Ramesh | Wooden sword      | 
| Khilan | Teddy bear        |
| Khilan | Chess             | 
| Khilan | Wooden sword      | 
+--------+-------------------+
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from ToyStore ts1 where 
exists (select 1 from ToyStore  ts2 where
ts1.name=ts2.name and purchase ='Teddy bear')
and
exists (select 1 from ToyStore  ts2 where
ts1.name=ts2.name and purchase ='Chess')
and
exists (select 1 from ToyStore  ts2 where
ts1.name=ts2.name and purchase ='Wooden sword')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all names with exact one row of each matching toy and only These three rows you could use the following query:
(of course there are smarter ways, but this is very easy to understand and to Change)

```
With 
-- Data
TOYSTORE AS (
  SELECT 1 ID, 'Ramish' NAME, 'Teddy Bear' PURCHASE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Khilan', 'Drum' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'Chaitali', 'Chess' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'Hardik', 'Wooden sword' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'Hardik', 'Chess' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 'Hardik', 'Teddy Bear' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 'Chaitali', 'Chess' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 'Chaitali', 'Wooden sword' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 9, 'Chaitali', 'Teddy Bear' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 10, 'Khilan', 'Chess' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, 'Khilan', 'Wooden sword' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 12, 'Khilan', 'Teddy Bear' FROM DUAL 
),
-- Matching items
MyMatches AS (
  SELECT 'Teddy Bear' PURCHASE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Chess' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Wooden sword' FROM DUAL
),
-- all single hits of matching items
MyStrikes AS (
  SELECT NAME, PURCHASE, COUNT(*) CNT
  FROM TOYSTORE 
  NATURAL JOIN MyMatches 
  GROUP BY NAME, PURCHASE 
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
),
-- all names with exactly one item of each kind
My3Strikes AS (
  SELECT NAME, SUM(CNT) CNT
  FROM MyStrikes
  GROUP BY NAME
  HAVING SUM(CNT) = 3
),
-- number of all not matching items
MyBlanks AS (
  SELECT NAME, COUNT(PURCHASE) CNT --COUNT(PURCHASE) CNT
  FROM TOYSTORE 
  WHERE NOT PURCHASE IN ('Teddy Bear', 'Chess', 'Wooden sword') 
  GROUP BY NAME 
),
-- all names
MyNames AS (
  SELECT D.NAME
  FROM TOYSTORE  D
  GROUP BY D.NAME
)
-- the result
SELECT D.NAME
FROM MyNames  D
JOIN My3Strikes S ON S.Name = D.Name
LEFT JOIN MyBlanks B ON B.Name = D.Name
WHERE B.CNT IS NULL
;
```

Answer (score -1):

There are some things not completely clear for me. Do you want to know, whether any 3 items are in list? If so, the next query would help.

```
SELECT NAME, COUNT(PURCHASE) 
FROM TOYSTORE 
GROUP BY NAME 
HAVING COUNT(PURCHASE) = 3
```

gives all names, that have exactly 3 items in his list.

This query you need for an inner join:

```
SELECT T.NAME, T.PURCHASE 
FROM TOYSTORE T
JOIN (
    SELECT NAME, COUNT(PURCHASE) 
    FROM TOYSTORE 
    GROUP BY NAME 
    HAVING COUNT(PURCHASE) = 3
) I
ON I.NAME = T.NAME
```

Does this solve your Problem?
If not, tell us more.

Questions may be: 
What, if someone buys 2 teddybears and 1 sword? 
What, if someone buys all three items and another more item?

Comment: These two queries are wrong - they give buyers which have made **exactly 3 purchases - but ANY purchases, not these 3 particular: Teddy bear, Chess and Wooden**. These queries return for example a name that has bought solely `Drum ` 3 times.

Comment: Yes, that I mentioned in the answer. I don't know, whether this matches the problem. Could even be asked for exactly one row for each item and no other. This would change the query completely. Interesting, I'll add such a query.